# The questions of AFNetWorking3.0 post Parameters Encode

Tags: ios, afnetworking-3

I use the AFNetWorking3.0, and use a tool (Wireshark) to get the post datas (request), eg I want to post a parameters like `@{"name": @"zlj"}`, the wireshark can get the right Datas, I can see `@{"name": @"zlj"}`.

But when I use like this, `NSDictionary *para = @{@"json": @{@"name": @"zlj", @"sex": @"1"}}`, and then I use AFNetWorking post this parameters , the wireshark get my post datas like -----`"json%5Bname%5D=zlj&json%5Bsex%5D=1"`

So I could not understand why show `"json%5Bname%5D=zlj&json%5Bsex%5D=1"`, why not show `"@{@"json": @{@"name": @"zlj", @"sex": @"1"}}"`,  Can somebody tell my?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to do is, instead of sending the dictionary direct to server , convert it to `JSON` serialization and send the data by `POST` as below.

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictionnary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary]; 
[dictionnary setObject:@"zlj" forKey:@"name"];  
[dictionnary setObject:@"1" forKey:@"sex"];

NSError *error = nil; 
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionnary options:kNilOptions  error:&error];
```

Then send the above jsonData to server through POST method , and it will work.

Comment: thanks,   ,,,there had a old project code,it use ASIHTTP to post, and i use wireshark can get the request post is like "mobileReqHeader" : {
    "appInfo" : {
      "verName" : "1.0",
      "chnlCode" : "xxxxx",
      "verCode" : "24",
      "userKey" : "81B5DEA6-4D56-40BE-BDA2-B93314610E07",
      "appCode" : "xxx",
      "platform" : "ios"
    },,       but i use afn3.0 ,it show some encode i can't understand like "%3C7b0a2020%20226d6f62%20696c6552%2065714865%20616465",i want know could show NSDictionary , but not the Json code or last?,thank you